# Confluent Kafka Backup and Recovery

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Is there a procedure in Kafka to take backup of Kafka broker data ?
How does backup and restore work in Kafka ?

Note-
The one method is to create another DC and configure inter DC replication .

But is there any other method to take backup of data ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/confluent-replicator/

Answer (score 2):

One approach I'd recommend is to continuously backup your **Kafka** data into **HDFS**. In order to do this, you can apply *Confluent HDFS-Sink* connector. You can store your records in Avro or Parquet format.

On the flip side, using HDFS as data source allows you to replay all your records into Kafka.

[1] Confluent HDFS-Sink: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html

Comment: There is no HDFS source connector, though